# Html dynamic page edit

Tags: html, edit

I want to make it possible for someone with a username and password to login and edit my html page using a nice clean editor. I don't want them to see the code when they log in to edit the page but a straightforward version of the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a proper CMS (Content Management System) is a huge undertaking. I suggest looking for a pre-built CMS to add to your site.